# Plotting graph with ax.axvspan

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot with axvspan, but it doesn't get anything plot and doesn't give me an error. Any idea? here the image and the code.[image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


xtime       = np.linspace(1,372,372)
#sp3 = sp3.reshape((360))

ax.plot(xtime, sp12, 'black', alpha=1.00, linewidth=2)
ax.fill_between(xtime, 0., sp12, sp12> 0., color='blue', alpha=.75)
ax.fill_between(xtime, 0., sp12, sp12< 0., color='red',  alpha=.75)


plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('SPI')
plt.title('SPI-12 Macuelizo[ (1985-2015)', fontsize=12)
ax.axhline(-0.6, color='red', label='SPI - 0.6')
ax.axhline(-1.3, color='magenta', label='SPI - 1.3')
ax.axvspan(1997, 1998, color='magenta', alpha=0.7)

ax.set_xlim(0, 372)
ax.set_ylim(-4, 3)
ax.set_xticklabels(range(1985,2016,1*4))


plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
ax.autoscale_view()

plt.savefig('SP12_macuelizo.jpg')
```

Comment: `ax.set_xlim(0, 372)` <-- what's up with this?

Comment: number of rows = months

Comment: so setting the span between 1997 and 1998 would be naturally out of bounds of those limits, right?

Comment: Right, So I need to know which numbers are between 1997 and 1998?

Comment: Yes. I recommend you work with actual date time objects. That'll make everything much more explicit and clear in your code